# How to add the commit comment to a Subversion post-commit hook

Tags: svn, post-commit, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I have a working Subversion Post Commit working OK - how do I add in the comments made by the user performing the commit?

My code is

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

AUTHOR="$(svnlook author -r $REV $REPOS)"

mailer.py commit "$REPOS" "$REV" /path/to/mailer.conf

# Script to send simple email when SVN is updated

# email subject
SUBJECT="[Project Name goes here] - new commit made in Subversion"

# Email To 
EMAIL="[email addresses go here]"

# Date and time
DATE="$(date)"

# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/buildingcontrolmessage.txt"
echo "The commit happened: " $DATE > $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Repository: " $1 >> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Reveision: " $2 >> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "The commit was made by: $AUTHOR"  >> $EMAILMESSAGE

# send an email using /bin/mail

/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

I'd just like to add a line in the e-mail to say:

```
echo "Comment: $MSG"  >> $EMAILMESSAGE
```

But I'm not sure how to get the message from the commit.

Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the commit message from the output of [svnlook info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.info.html).
Documentation:

> Print the author, datestamp, log message size (in bytes), and log message, followed by a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case other people want to do the same - here's what I did in the end:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
AUTHOR="$(svnlook author -r $REV $REPOS)"
MESSAGE="$(svnlook log $REPOS)"


mailer.py commit "$REPOS" "$REV" /path/to/mailer.conf

# Script to send simple email when SVN is updated

# email subject
SUBJECT="New commit made in Subversion"

# Email To ?
EMAIL="[email address or addresses]"

# Date and time
DATE="$(date)"

# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessagemessage.txt"
echo "The commit happened: " $DATE > $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Repository: " $1 >> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Reveision: " $2 >> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "The commit was made by: $AUTHOR"  >> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Comment: $MESSAGE" >> $EMAILMESSAGE

# send an email using /bin/mail
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Comment: ok, this is way easier... :) but maybe also add ` -r $REV` to the call.